# Ubuntu not so friendly to other softwares

Tags: sound, firefox, google-chrome, flash

I have just installed ubuntu 16.04, and although it's friendly regarding basic softwares, it is just a hassel to install other softwares.

**1st question**

how do I get rid of the ((voice)) without muting the media sound?

**2nd question**

I cannot play any facebook applications using firefox or chrome. 
The game acts as if it is playing, but it is a white screen, cannot see any thing happening although I have installed all plugins I could reach including adobe flash player.

Comment: What ((voice))?

Comment: There is a man's voice that names and deccripes every place the cursor is on. for example; the menu and any roll down item under the menu

Comment: It is the man voice that descripes every menu item the cusror is on.  plus when I type the password. the same voice gives a sound on every keyboard butten push

Comment: To turn Screen reader off press Alt+Super+S

Comment: Turn it off as follows: System Settings -> Universal Access. First tab ("Sight"): Screen Reader -> OFF.

Answer (score 1):

**General regarding flash on Linux**

In case you really need flash - consider using Google Chrome instead of Mozilla Firefox.

Google Chrome should come with a bundled flash for Linux.

**How to get Google Chrome for Linux**

Download Chrome from the [google page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html). The downloaded file should be a .deb file.

**How to install local .deb**

Either doubleclick the .deb or run the following command in a terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/localfile.deb
```

Google Chrome should add a custom source to your system, which will be used in the future to update Chrome

**Final general hint**

It helps to create separate questions/posts for each question you might have.

Comment: Actually that is what most answers say. and the application it self asked for it., however I have insalled chrome, but yet the same thing. Now if there is a special vesion of chrome for ububtu. I will follow your instructions. So I understand that .deb file is the exe file. right??

Comment: If you have installed Chrome already - then forget my instructions.  I was just pointing out that Google Chrome must be manually installed, while Chromium is installable via the default sources

Comment: Regarding your .exe question: .exe are usually executables in the Windows- world,  where installable packages in the Debian/Ubuntu world come as .deb files.

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually I searched for Chromium, but I got Chrome. If chromium works fine then I will get it. but do I have to uninstall Chrome and how?